# Partition Implementation for Recursive Quicksort in Java is not working

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, quicksort, partitioning

Wrote this Java implementation of a recursive quicksort algorithm, and something seems to go awry as the array I am trying to sort almost sorts perfectly except for two elements that should be switched (near the middle of the array). The array of integers I am trying to sort is: 4, 77, 98, 30, 20, 50, 77, 22, 49, 2 (10 elements). Here is my code:

```
public static void quickSort(int[] array, int start, int end) {
    if (start < end) {
        int partition = partition(array, start, end);
        quickSort(array, start, partition - 1);
        quickSort(array, partition + 1, end);
    }
}

public static int partition(int[] array, int left, int right) {
    int pivotValue = array[(left + right) / 2]; //Value of middle element in array
    while (left <= right) {
        while (array[left] < pivotValue) {
            left++;
        }
        while (array[right] > pivotValue) {
            right++;
        }
        if (left <= right) {
            /* swap code */
            int temporary = array[left]
            array[left] = array[right]
            array[right] = temporary;

            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }
    return left;
}
```

When I try this algorithm out with:

```
int[] array = {4, 77, 98, 30, 20, 50, 77, 22, 49, 2};
quickSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
}
```

It prints out:
2, 4, 20, **30, 22**, 49, 50, 77, 77, 98

Any help figuring out why those two elements aren't correctly sorted would be highly appreciated. I'm sure it's something I missed while writing the partition code. Thanks!

Comment: You should do some debugging to isolate the problem.

Comment: I was thinking of doing some print outs, although I was planning to do that after I wrote the working algorithm so I could understand the entire algorithm better. I understand the underlying logic of the quicksort algorithm, but a trace is always helpful IMO. Problem is I'm not really sure what I'm even looking for. I tried playing around with some of the comparisons, but most of them ended up in stack overflows or index out of bounds errors.

Comment: You should be looking for any divergence between the observed behaviour and the anticipated behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are leaving 1 element to be checked
just replace your code :

```
quickSort(array, start, partition - 1);
quickSort(array, partition + 1, end);
```

with this :

```
quickSort(array, start, partition - 1);
quickSort(array, partition, end);
```

or with this :

```
quickSort(array, start, partition);
quickSort(array, partition + 1, end);
```

I am assuming that the reason is clear now, but tell me if you need some explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For some reason I was under the impression that the pivot index had to be "left out" when partitioning the two sides for more sorting. Thanks for clearing that up.